# JQ filter and github api

Tags: bash, api, jq, github-api

I have a simple task to write the script with curl and jq, which will print the number of pull requests of each contributor has created with the labels.
I was able to filter pull requests by contributor:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/jina-ai/jina/pulls?state=opened | jq '. [] | .user.login, .labels'
```

But how to deal next, maybe U can sugest something.

Thanks

Comment: Show us an input and an output sample.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub API tells if there are more result pages in the `link` header.

You can obtain the last result page by parsing the `link` header for example with `awk` like this:

*The `per_page=1` is here to force excessive paging of the results for the purpose of demonstrating how to parse GitHub API's `link` header.*.

**DO NOT DO THIS IN PRODUCTION** as it would be very inefficient

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

API='https://api.github.com'

# DO NOT SET IT TO 1 IN PRODUCTION
per_page=1

# Get the last page
last_page=$(
  curl \
    --silent \
    --head \
    --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
    --url "${API}/repos/jina-ai/jina/pulls?per_page=${per_page}&state=opened" |
      awk -F',' '
/^link:/{
  for(i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
    if(match($i, "[&?]page=([0-9]+).*rel=\"last\"", a)) print a[1]
  }
}'
)

# In case there is no paging, we need to set this to 1)
last_page=${last_page:-1}

for ((page=1; page <= last_page; page++)); do
  curl \
    --silent \
    --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
    --url "${API}/repos/jina-ai/jina/pulls?per_page=${per_page}&page=${page}&state=opened" |
    jq '.[] | (.user.login, .labels)'
done
```

Comment: Hi, this won't work, it will show just the names contributors with empty labels, like this:
"decaylala"
[]
"MuzafferDede"
[]
"hendrasob"
[]

Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, you can conditionally display labels with `jq`. I let you do a bit of search how to `if then end` with `jq`.